# getting php array to javascript: variable undefined

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

What I want is perform some addition of values on dynamic input fields but its showing variable not found.
Here is my form input field

```
<input type="text" name="test[]" placeholder="test" onchange=calculate();>
```

my javascript function

```
function calculate() {
    var test = <?php echo json_encode($test); ?>;
    alert(test);
    console.log(test);
}
```

and I have a save.php file which insert data to MySQL

```
foreach($_POST['name'] as $key => $val) {
    $proj = $_POST['project'][$key];
    $test = $_POST['test'][$key];
    $insert = "INSERT INTO test (name,project,test) values ('$val','$proj', '$test')";
    $result = $conn->query($insert);
}
```

Comment: **Warning: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: I know @MagnusEriksson I was just trying it with simple query.

Comment: Is there any way I can get data of dynamically created inputs in javascript and perform calculations?